# Using sum() in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

How can I write the sql query `select sum(amount * direction) from transactions` into hibernate criteria ?

Comment: @Closevoter - this **is** a real question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Think I found the answer. You must use the Projection.sqlProjection() and not Projections.sum(). Example:

```
.setProjection(Projections.sqlProjection("sum(cast(amount as signed)* direction) as amntDir", new String[] {"amntDir"} , new Type[] {Hibernate.DOUBLE}));
```

Comment: Can you develop your answer ? 
-What is your initial query : createQuery("....")
-Where the result is put ? (into amntDir?)
-How you use the result ?

Answer (score 6):

I think what you need is formula. Something like this,

```
@Entity
@Table('TRANSACTIONS')
Class transactions {

     @Column("AMOUNT")
     private double amount;

     @Column("DIRECTION")
     private double direction;

     @Formula("AMOUNT * DIRECTION")
     private double multiplication;

}
```

And add multiplication column to your projection list.

Answer (score 1):

*Projections* is the key word to use aggregate functions with hibnerate criteria.

[roseindia has a short example](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/projections/projection-hibernate-example1.shtml) for implementing a `SELECT SUM(...)` query. Looks pretty close to your problem.

---

[Here's another forum topic](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=942279) that includes a working example for a `SUM(col1 * col2)` expression and the original poster had similiar problems with exceptions before.

Comment: I tried with ".setProjection(Projections.sum(("amount * direction")))" but it gives me an exception "org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: amount * direction ...."