# What is Hibernate equivalent of Projections.Cast?

Tags: hibernate

I have fixed my problem using HQL and it is working great.

But I do like Criteria API. (I have a few ifs statements in my querybuilder string for HQL, yuck) 
Apparently Projections.sum(property) return double.

My Entity class has

```
@Column(name = "current_volume")   
private Integer currentVolume;
```

The error I get is

> org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of se.unox.pejl.entity.value.pejl.PejlDataTrendValue.currentVolume.

My equivalent working hql is

```
select cast(sum(p.currentVolume/1000) as integer) as currentVolume from      
se.unox.pejl.entity.value.pejl.PejlDataTrendValue as p
```

I think I know what the problem is, but cannot figure out how to cast sum of columns (which is INT(11) in mysql) into Integer. Apparently NHibernate has Projections.Cast

I am using Hibernate 3.6

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this blog post](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide35) (unless something was changed between 3.5 and 3.6), the return type of `Projections.sum` is dependent on the property type of the property being summed:

> for properties mapped as Long, Short, Integer, or primitive integer types, a Long value is returned;
>
> for properties mapped as Float, Double, or primitive floating point types, a Double value is returned.

If you want to override native functionality, [follow the answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624807/using-sum-in-hibernate-criteria).

Comment: Thanks Aron! So it becomes Long instead of double I assumed. No wonder i get Exception. The Entity class is years old and i dont really want to change it.

What I was looking for is simple NHibernate style casting in new piece of code I added and not touch the old one. 

I guess I will stick to HQL then.

Comment: That being the case, try the override linked to in the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I am not sure about writing at Database columns names (SQL Projections), when I have my Entity bean with mapped properties.