# Hibernate criteria + calculation in Projection List

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

### Invoice

<kbd>id</kbd><kbd>description</kbd><kbd>rate</kbd><kbd>amount</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Invoice A</kbd>    <kbd>3.0</kbd> <kbd>10.0</kbd>    
<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Invoice B</kbd>    <kbd>4.0</kbd> <kbd>20.0</kbd>    
<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Invoice C</kbd>    <kbd>5.0</kbd> <kbd>30.0</kbd>

```
DetachedCriteria criteria= DetachedCriteria.forClass(Invoice.class)

ProjectionList projList = new ProjectionList(); 
projList.add(...);

criteria.setProjection(projList);

List list = myDAO.findByCriteria(criteria); 

//260
```

Using projection list, is it possible to calculate (amount * rate) and return the sum for all records?

Update 1:

```
   double dblAmount = 0.0;
   for(Invoice invoice : list){
     dblAmount = dblAmount + (invoice.getRate() * invoice.getAmount());
   }
```

Using Hibernate 4, I heard that without specifying joins, using this way (invoice.getSomething()) has performance impact?

Comment: This is a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624807/using-sum-in-hibernate-criteria

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `@Formula` derived property and then create a projection on that:

Derived property:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="INVOICE")
public class Invoice {
    private double rate;
    private double amount;
    @Formula("rate * amount")
    private double computed;
    // ...
}
```

Projection:

```
Projections.sum("computed")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
double sum=0;   
ProjectionList projList = new ProjectionList(); 
projList.add(Projections.property("rate"));
projList.add(Projections.property("amount"));
criteria.setProjection(projList);
List list=criteria.list();

for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
   double d=1;
   Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next(); 
   for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) { 
     d=d*Double.parseDouble(row[i].toString());
   } 
   sum=sum+d;
  }
return sum;
```

try this.

Comment: This works, but am wondering if there is difference in performance compared with (see update). I have a feeling this should be faster.