# Hibernate -select sum of multiple columns grouped by

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm working on a Java EE project using Hibernate and Mysql, and I'm new in working with an ORM. I have an Entity table simliar to this one:

```
@Entity
myClass
{
    @Id
    int id;
    int quantity1;
    int quantity2;
    int quantity3;
    String Groupe;
}
```

and here is an example of Data:

[image: example of data]

What I want to do is selecting sum of each quanity for each `groupe` using Hql 
but I dont know how to handle it.

Comment: First form a regular SQL and then map your SQL to HQL. Try splitting query in parts and implementing them separately if it gets too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is ORM tool, used to persist the beans or POJOS to relation databases. For summation of the values you can fetch all the records and than add the required values.

Comment: which will take more time and more resources , instand of selecting 3 lines , i have to select the whole 5 objects and calculate them manualy using a loop

Comment: That's what you have to do, hibernate will not calculate sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Projections` to do it. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624807/using-sum-in-hibernate-criteria) could help you.