# Hibernate criteria left join with query

Tags: sql, hibernate, group-by, criteria, projection

I have two classes Apartment and AdditionalSpace representing tables as below.

Apartment table

```
ID    AREA  SOLD  
---- ------ ----
1      100    1   
2      200    0
```

AdditionalSpace table

```
ID    AREA  APARTMENTID
---- ------ -----------
10     10     1
11     10     1
12     10     1
20     20     2
21     20     2
```

As  you can see Apartment's table has a one-to-many relation with AdditionalSpace table, i.e. Apartment.ID=AdditionalSpace.APARTMENTID.

Question:- How to retrieve total area of a sold apartment including its additional space area.

The SQL which I have used so far to retrieve similar result is :-

```
select sum(apt.area + ads.adsarea) from apartment apt left outer join (select sum(area) as adsarea, apartmentid from additionalspace group by apartmentid) ads on ads.apartmentid=apt.id where apt.sold=1
```

I am struggling to find a way in order to implement the above scenario via criteria instead of SQL/HQL. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using an sqlProjection as suggested in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624807/using-sum-in-hibernate-criteria

Comment: @Hedley - Thanks for your answer. I tried with sqlProjection as below however was not able achieve the desired result. 
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(AdditionalSpace .class, "ads");
criteria.createAlias("apartmentid", "aid");  
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("aid.id", new BigDecimal(1)));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("aid.sold", new BigDecimal(1)));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.sqlProjection("sum({alias}.area) as areaVal", new String[] {"areaVal"} , new Type[]{new LongType()}));

The above code works and give areaVal=30, but not sure how to get 130. Please suggest.

Comment: I've posted what I think is the closest you can achieve. Was there a particular reason why you want to write this in criteria as opposed to HQL?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in criteria. The closest I can see is to simply get the size of the apartment and the sum of the additional areas as two columns in your result, like this:

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Apartment.class,"a");
    criteria.createAlias("additionalSpaces", "ads");
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("area"))
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("a.id"))
        .add(Projections.sum("ads.area")));
```

Alternatively, if you still want to use Hibernate but are happy to write it in HQL, you can do the following:

```
select ads.apartment.id,max(a.area)+sum(ads.area) 
from Apartment a 
join a.additionalSpaces ads 
group by ads.apartment.id
```

This works because HQL allows you to write the + to add together the two projections, but I don't know that an analogous method exists on the projections api.